# Directories Exceeding a Certain Size?

Tags: linux, macos, unix

I misread [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/64481/is-there-a-windows-command-line-utility-to-list-largest-files-exceeding-specific) and thought it was asking something I've needed for a long time. My question is slightly different: **how to find directories whose contents exceed a certain size.** Is there any *nix way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`find` doesn't look at the cumulative size of subdirectories. Instead, use `du` with the `-s` option to tell it to print only the total size of each directory given on the command line:

```
du -s *|awk '{ if ($1 > 3000) print }'
```

will give you output like:

```
3124    foo
10025   bar
```

or, to print just the names:

```
du -s *|awk '{ if ($1 > 3000) print $2 }'
```

Answer (score 1):

Does `find . -type d -size +3k -print` do what you are asking?  Change the "3k" to whatever size you want, of course.

Comment: @mpez0, I'm not sure. I'm trying it but I haven't decided how it's handling the subdirs yet. Ideally I'd like it to report only the top level directories whose recursive contents exceed the size. That way I can go down levels to investigate, or not.

Comment: Recursive content?  If you're looking for the size of the *content* of the directories, use the "du" (disk usage) command.  Find will be looking at the actual size of the directory file itself

Answer (score 1):

A couple expansions on Peter Westlake's answer:

- The --max-depth option can be used to limit the depth of subdirectories du will search.  In the example below the search is to 2 levels.
- You can use the -B option for du to set a block size for the du output.  In the following example, the directory size is kilobytes (1000 bytes here).  For now, you may be able to use the -k (kilobytes) and -m (megabytes) options, but man tells me they are deprecated, so I would recommend you avoid them.  (Otherwise you'll be in the situation I may end up in - in the habit of using them and frustrated when they go away!)

  $ du --max-depth=2 -B 1000 | awk '{if($1>=5) print $0};'

One more point:  If you want the output sorted by directory size, pipe it through sort -n, which will sort the output numerically (the -n) and default to using the first column (the directory size).